# Swift : How to have 2 different cells in 1 tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to have 2 different cells in my table view.

For example :

1. My first cell have 1 image view and 1 label.
2. My second cell have 4 images views and 4 labels

It's possible ? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard with prototype cells?

Comment: I had prototype cells and I've just think to use static cells. I have only 2 cells, so useless to have a dynamic tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two custom `UITableViewCell` and and register them with tableView with cellIdentifiers like "CellType1" and cellType2 and then you can do something like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
// first row, return cell you want 
cellIdentifier = @"CellType1";
}
else 
{
// other rows you can return cell you want
cellIdentifier = @"CellType2";
}
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### storyboard version

1. just drop a TableViewController , and set the property on the right panel. set the type to prototype and you can just drop anything you want to it, like imgView or UILabel
2. then in the controller , just use the cell you just created in
   `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`